# How can I convert pre-1950 stereocopic photos to cardboard?

Tags: 3d, stereoscopy

Before Google Cardboard come to the idea of replacing expensive glasses which filtered quickly-alternating images (or low-cost glasses which filtered different color images) with simply one static image for each eye, that method was used widely on the decades that span between 1890 to 1940.

I wonder if there is some application to convert such old stereoscopic images (those postcards with one image for each eye, intended to be viewed with a special viewer) to cardboard. I guess that it should be simple, because you already have a different image for each eye and just need to change image centers to match those of Google Cardboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File formats for stereoscopic 3D images](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/109457/file-formats-for-stereoscopic-3d-images)

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Most any stereo viewer for Cardboard will take .JPS files. Just scan your postcard as a .JPG and change the extension to .JPS (meaning JPG Stereo)

Example viewer app: 3D/VR Stereo Photo Viewer
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andymodla.apps.vrstereophotoviewer